# Responisve Full Width CSS Divided in 3

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'd like to use a Grid system, like Skeleton CSS Boilerplate, to build a responsive website. I know there's a ton other boilerplates out there for 960 or w/e pixels wide.

But I'd like to have a responsive full width page, divided in 3 by 3 columns. Like 33.33% wide and 33.33% high per column (so 9 divs alltogether). I've used tables, but I rather don't use them.

What would be best practice to make a 3 by 3 column full width responsive website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Gridpak](http://gridpak.com/)

It allows you to specify how many columns you want and add breakpoints to completely alter the grid at different window dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [CSS3 columns](http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns).